# Updating a one to many relationship without the use of implode laravel

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, updates

I am trying to update my data into my database where the relationship is that I have many schools, so when I try to save inside my database, I want to get something like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But I only know how to use implode function to do it, and I can only make it like this:

I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
public function update1(Request $request, $user_id){
$rows = qualification::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        switch ($row['meta_key']){
            case 'school_name':
                $row['meta_value'] = $request->input('School');
                break;
            case 'start_date':
                $row['meta_value'] = $request->input('SDate');
                break;
            case 'end_date':
                $row['meta_value'] = $request->input('EDate');
                break;
            case 'qualification_list':
                $row['meta_value'] = $request->input('qualification');
                break;
        }
        $row->save();
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

When I try using that code it will give me this error, Array to string conversion
PersonalInfo model:

```
class PersonalInfo extends Eloquent
{
     use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function userQualifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Qualification','user_id');
    }
```

Qualification model:

```
class Qualification extends Model
{
    protected $table = "qualifications";

        public function PersonalInfos() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PersonalInfo');
    }
}
```

No error message:
[image]

Comment: So all of your ```$request``` values are arrays in this case?

Comment: Yes, I just want to make it save just into the database like in the first screenshot but I don't know how, in the past I did something like this, it works but now I don't know why

Comment: what is your expected output please add that

Comment: @kunal the output is shown in the second screenshot, but I want to make it so it will save like the first screenshot

Comment: can you please add the  the post data  array so i will resolve your issue @Dkna

Comment: post data array? you mean when I used dd the result?

Comment: yes exactly print that and add in question

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all); die;

Comment: @kunal it just return me a blank page

Comment: public function update1(Request $request, $user_id){  
echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all); die; } like this

Comment: @Dkna, There should be one more field to indicate `id` of school, in order to match one user to several schools.

Comment: @Miron I can't use user_id?

Comment: That's because you can't specify one school with `user_id` when a user is mapped to multiple schools. Besides, you are misunderstanding one to many relationship. Since rows of your table are not similar objects, and they are properties of one school, you can't handle them as object. Usually, I used to avoid such structure when I develop web application by Laravel. I prefer your previous structure.

Comment: So you are saying that I should have something like maybe id2 column for school? Something like that? @Miron

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your relationship setup properly in your User model, you could try something like this (not tested):

```
public function update1(Request $request, $user_id){

    // get the user
    $user = PersonalInfo::find($user_id);

    // create the new array of meta data
    $data = array();

    // loop through the inputs array count
    for($i=0; $i < count($request->input('School')); $i++) {
        $data[] = [
            'meta_key' => 'school_name',
            'meta_value' => $request->input('School')[$i]
        ];
        $data[] = [
            'meta_key' => 'start_date',
            'meta_value' => $request->input('SDate')[$i]
        ];
        $data[] = [
            'meta_key' => 'end_date',
            'meta_value' => $request->input('EDate')[$i]
        ];
        $data[] = [
            'meta_key' => 'qualification_list',
            'meta_value' => $request->input('qualification')[$i]
        ];
    }

    // create the relationships
    $user->userQualifications()->createMany($data);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error? "Call to undefined method App\PersonalInfo::qualifications()" Does this mean my relationship has some problems?

Comment: Can you please paste in your PersonalInfo model?

Comment: I have posted them in the question, i think it should be right if I am not wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer. Use ```$user->userQualifications()->create($data);```

Comment: I am getting a no error message now, could you tell me where should i do a dd so that I could show you where the problem is coming from? Because I have no idea where to start whenever there is a no message error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159634/discussion-between-cugreen-and-dkna).